# MySQL trying to ADD a multiple CHECK constraints

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I'm trying to make a CHECK constraint that checks that employees who work in department 1 must earn >=24000.

this is what i've used:

```
ALTER TABLE employees
ADD CONSTRAINT min_sal CHECK(dept_no = 1 AND salary >=24000);
```

However, I'm getting 'check constraint min_sal is violated' error message.

How do i add a constraint that checks if the employee is working in department 1, then they must earn >=24000?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have data which violates that rule?

Answer (score 3):

*checks that employees who work in department 1 must earn >=24000.*

I.e. check that dept_no is not department 1, or salary >= 24000 (in case of department 1.)

```
ALTER TABLE employees
ADD CONSTRAINT min_sal CHECK(dept_no <> 1 OR salary >=24000);
```

**Edit:** To find already existing rows violating the constraint:

```
select * from employees
where dept_no = 1 and salary < 24000
```

Comment: This makes sense, but for some reason, i am still getting the same error message: ERROR 3819 CHECK constraint min_sal is violated

Comment: What do you want to do with those employees?

Comment: I'm trying to split empployees between 2 departments. those working in department 1 earn >=24000 but those working in department 2 earn > 30000. so far i've only inserted the employees who work in department 1 into my table.

Comment: Here's a demo https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fc7f0f27c3789f49095b3b34594f7371. But you still have to decide how to handle existing department 1 staff having a salary below 24000.